# how to customize More Tabbar on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

after i have add 6 or more tabbar on the InterfaceBuilder it will automatically generate More Tab. how to customize look and feel of it ? eg Navigation bar color.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the `moreNavigationController` property of `UITabBarController`. It is a `NavigationController`, you cannot replace it but maybe you can change the color of the top bar.

Comment: UINavigationController * moreNav = tabBarController.moreNavigationController;

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to change the color of the Tab Bar "More" navigation bar, use something like the following code:

```
    self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

2. If you want to remove the Edit Button, appearing on the right side, you would want to do something like the following:

```
    -(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
        UINavigationBar *morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar;
        UINavigationItem morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem;
        / Remove the RIGHT bar button item... */
        morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
```

Lastly, the most important point, set the Tab Bar delegate to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

After looking to solve this myself I found a very useful link that explains it well.

[How to change more tab colours](http://runmad.com/blog/2010/01/coloring-fun-with-morenavigationcontroller-and-it/)

Hope this helps.